# Java - Sending a format string with data over network

Tags: java, networking, internationalization

Situation: `Server` wants to display message to a `Client`. `Server` doesn't know `Client's language`, just the format string and the data to be inserted into that string. The `Client` has a `ResourceBundle` that allows it to translate the format string to a format string of the Client's language. The problem now is sending the "arguments" to the format string along with the string over the network.

What methods are there to do this properly?

One way might be to just send the string and the list of arguments, but there could be issues with this(like the server inserting the wrong string format arguments, yet the error message appearing on the client).

Comment: Formatting on the server is no option?

Comment: It's a last resort, yes. =) Having to contact the server when locally changing language would be rather inefficient IMHO.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with sending format string and arguments separately. If that's a problem you need a better client-server communications lib.

Comment: That's right. I just thought that there might be an "official" way to do it. I'd have asked for the "best" way to do it, but didn't want to spark arguments. ;) I'll rephrase the question to just ask for different ways to do it.

Comment: The first question would be: do you really need that local language switching? How many users will ever use that feature? If the answer is yes, I am not sure what you are formatting, but if it regards to dates or numbers sending it in universal format and use client-side library for formatting sounds like a good idea.